# Pop Up not appearing in browser window

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I'm writing code to display a pop up box and my code is

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
windows.alert("Hello");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when i run this code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `windows` which has no meaning in JavaScript.

Change that to `window`. And the code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.alert("Hello"); 
</script>
```

Windows is a product of Microsoft; or a carpenter, it has nothing to do with JavaScript. Window is used in JavaScript!

When you'll run this code, you'll get an alert box saying `Hello`.

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/zSf6q/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello");
</script>
</body>
<html>
```